# In Java how can I figure out how many of a certain letter appears in a string with recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

So I need to use recursive programming to figure out how many times a certain letter appears in a word. For example, the word "complete" would have 2 e's. I kind of know what I need to do but I am just not sure how to do it. I currently have a scanner set up to take the word from the user, but that is all I have coded at the moment. I feel like the pseudocode should be something like;

Take word from user

if (letter <= 0)

return 1;

else
 return length of characters in word

I am guessing that I use the length or charAt method somehow?
I really need some guidance here, like how does the recursion come in? Is that because it breaks down the word until it finds the amount of "e's" remaining? Would the base case be 0?I really appreciate the help! I am really new to this. Thank you very much.

Comment: The number of the occurrences of 'x' in a string is 1 or 0 plus the number of occurrences of 'x' in that string without the first character. Try working with that. P.S. An empty string has exactly zero such occurrences.

Comment: Hint: The base case should be empty string or single character. Then think about how you would do it manually for one more character than that. Generalize to one more than N. Turn that into code. (This is not a good place to use recursion, by the way; it's a problem much more easily solved with simple iteration.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) {

        String myString = "Your test string here...";

        List< Character > alreadyDone = new ArrayList< Character >( );

        for ( Character myChar: myString.toCharArray( ) ) {

            if ( alreadyDone.contains( myChar ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println( myChar + ": " + getCount( myString, myChar ) );
            alreadyDone.add( myChar );
        }

    }

    // recursive method to calculate the occurrence of a character in a string

    private static int getCount( String string, char myChar ) {

        if ( string.length( ) == 0 ) {
            return 0;
        }

        if ( string.charAt( 0 ) == myChar ) {
            return 1 + getCount( string.substring( 1 ), myChar );
        }

        return getCount( string.substring( 1 ), myChar );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `substring` and `charAt`. Here's the pseudocode:

```
CountLetter(string, letter)
1. if string.length() == 0 then return 0
2. if string.charAt(0) == letter then
3.     return CountLetters(string.substring(1), letter) + 1
4. else then return CountLetter(string, letter)
```

Basically, recursive calls should use smaller versions of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much! Substring makes more sense to me. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I'll give you hints. Think of it this way:

```
num_occurrence(char, str) = num_occurrence(char, str[0]) + num_occurrence(char, str[1:])
```

Now think of what you can do meaningfully in the following cases:

1. `num_occurrence(char, str)` where `str` is an empty string. Can you return a meaningful value for the number of occurrences of `char` in an empty string?
2. `num_occurrence(char, str)` where `str` is a single letter. What value would you return in this case? It depends on what the character is inside `str`, right?
3. `num_occurrence(char, str)` where `str` has more than one character. Can you break this down in terms of the above cases?

Comment: Thank you for the help, appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Instance of doing this with a recursive method, assuming you store the word in a String word variable :

```
String word //(your word)

public int howMany(char c, String word) {
    // stop condition
    if(word.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }


    if(word.charAr(index) == c) {
      return 1 + howMany(c, word.substring(1, word.length));
    }
    else {
      return 0 + howMany(c, word.substring(1, word.length));
    }
}
```

The trick is to call the method with the world without its first letter, and do it again, and again, until there is no more letter.

Comment: "The trick is to call the method with the world without its first letter, and do it again, and again, until there is no more letter." That really clicked!! Thank you!

Comment: btw: the simplest / most appreciated way to say "thank you" here is to upvote useful answers (and to accept one if applicable)

Answer (score 0):

The pseudocode probably should be more like this:

- If the word is empty, return 0
- If the first letter is an 'e', return 1 + the number of 'e's in the rest of the word
- Otherwise, return the number of 'e's in the rest of the word.

In Java, you get the rest of the word with `word.substring(1)`. This method of counting is quite inefficient but ok for the purpose of learning recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! Substring - that is exactly what I was needing :)